# High order central moments of a symmetric binomial variable

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability

Consider a random variable $X\sim B(n,\frac 12)$. I'm trying to estimate the asymptotic behaviour of its central moments $E((X-\frac n2)^r)$, where $r$ is even and in the range $\Omega(1)\leq r\leq O(n)$, and $n$ goes to $\infty$.

I've looked at inequalities for central moments of sums of independent variables, but they seem too general. I'd be very grateful if someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: You can use the binomial formula to get exact expression. Better suited for math exchange.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, the binomial formula yields an exact expression, but what I'm looking for is the asymptotic growth of this expression. I will edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: I think it is a reasonable question. To clarify, do you want a strict upper bound or instead the asymptotic behaviour as $n \rightarrow \infty$? A normal approximation of the Binomial random variable quickly gives you $E((X-n/2)^r) \approx (\sqrt{n}/2)^r (r-1)!!$, where $(r-1)!! = (r-1)(r-3) ... 1$.

Comment: By exact I actually meant you can write the expectation as a closed form function of N, r. It will involve some special functions, but their asymptotic behavior is pretty well undetstood. My mathematica is broken right now but I will try to do it once it's reinstalled.

Comment: If the exponent is large (say, proportional to $n$), it looks tricky to get the asymptotics.

Comment: Joris, I mean asymptotic behaviour as $n\to \infty$. I considered the normal approximation, but from the central limit theorem (at least the standard version), I'm not sure how to bound the error here.

Comment: John, can you tell me what special functions are you referring to? Thanks!

Comment: As $r$ becomes large, the important parts of the distribution for the $r$-th moment move away from the centre.  I think it is the values around $c\sqrt{rn}$ that count.  So I don't expect the moments of the normal approximation to be good for very large $r$.

Comment: Surely it has been done before, but I'd do it thus: the mgf is $$E e^{tX} = 2^{-n}e^{-tn/2}(e^t+1)^n.$$ Now estimate the coefficient of $t^r$ using the saddle-point method (or otherwise).

Comment: @Yonatan turns out I was wrong. There are only exact formula for uncentered moments, like $EX^{2r}$. They are expressible in terms of hypergeometric functions. Brendan's suggestion to use saddle point analysis is the correct one.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay, I'll try your suggestion and post an answer if I succeed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M:=(E(X-n/2)^r)^{1/r}$. 
By Corollary 2 in **[[Latala](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aop/1024404522)]**, 
$M\sim S$, where $A\sim B$ means that $\frac1C\,B\le A\le C B$ for some universal positive constant $C$ and 
\begin{equation}
 S:=r\sup\{t(2n/r)^t\colon1/r\le t\le t_*\}, 
\end{equation}
where $t_*:=\frac12\wedge\frac nr$. It is not hard to see that $t(2n/r)^t$ increases in $t\in[1/r,t_*]$, and so, 
$S=rt_*(2n/r)^{t_*}$. 
Thus, 
$M\sim\sqrt{nr}$ if $r\le2n$ and $M\sim n(n/r)^{n/r}\sim n$ if $r\ge2n$. 
That is, $M\sim\sqrt{n(r\wedge n)}$.

Comment: Thanks! This reference is pretty much what I was looking for.

Comment: Since I'm interested in $M^r$, this gives an estimate tight up to a factor exponential in $r$. Will update if I find anything better. Again, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if this perhaps-naive approach can help you. Let's shift by the mean, so consider $X = \sum_{j=1}^n X_j$ where each $X_j = 0.5$ or $-0.5$ independently with one-half probability each. So $\mathbb{E} X^r$ should be the value you're looking for. Now,

\begin{align}
  X^r &= \left(X_1 + \dots + X_n\right)^r  \\
  &= \sum_{\text{$j_1,\dots,j_r$}} ~~ \prod_{s=1}^r X_{j_s}
\end{align}
where the sum is over all vectors $(j_1,\dots,j_r)$ of indices in $\{1,\dots,n\}$.
Now the expectation of the sum is the sum of the expectations, so let's look at the expectation of one term:
\begin{align}
 \mathbb{E} \prod_{s=1}^r X_{j_s}
  &= \left(0.5^r\right) \mathbb{E} \prod_{s=1}^r \begin{cases} 1 & X_{j_s} > 0 \\ -1 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} \\
  &= \left(0.5^r\right) \begin{cases} 1 & \text{each index appears in $\vec{j}$ an even number of times}  \\
           0 & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}
\end{align}
(Why is this true? We split the product into a product over distinct indices $j$ of $X_j^{m(j)}$, where $m(j)$ is the multiplicity of $j$ in the multiset. The indices are independent Bernoullis, so the expectation of the product is the product of the expectations. Each distinct index's expected product is 1 if that index has even multiplicity and zero if odd.)

So if I've made no mistakes, **the expectation you're looking for is equal to $0.5^r$ times the number of vectors in $\{1,\dots,n\}^r$ where each $j \in \{1,\dots,n\}$ appears in the vector an even number of times.**

Example: For $r=2$, there are $n$ vectors of all-even multiplicity (one for each index, where that index appears twice), so we get $0.5^2*n = n/4$. For $r=4$, there are $n$ vectors containing just $1$ element and $6{n\choose 2}$ vectors containing two elements twice each (because there are six ways to arrange 2 indices into 4 slots, each taking two). So we get $0.5^4 \left(n + 6{n \choose 2}\right) = \frac{1}{16}\frac{2n + 6n^2 - 6n}{2} = \frac{3n^2}{16} - \frac{n}{8}$ (which is also correct -- it's nice to check).

I didn't get to think about how hard this is to estimate in general (I hope someone much more knowledgable in combinatorics can comment).

Comment: From this it is easy to recover the exact formula $2^{-n}\sum_j\binom{n}{n/2+j} j^r$, but I don't know to get asymptotics from it directly.

Comment: @usul, you've actually given my motivation for asking this question. I started by looking for the asymptotics of the number of sequences of vectors in $\{1\ldots n\}^r$ in which each element appears an even number of times. :-)

Comment: @Yonatan, aww, well, it's nice to see the connection but sorry it wasn't useful!

Answer (score 0):

Symmetric Binomial $B(n,1/2)$ has sub-gaussian tails with variance-proxy $\sigma^2 = n/4$. Thus the growth of of the $r$-th moment is at most $(\mathbf{E}\|S\|^r)^{1/r} = O(\sqrt{r}\cdot \sigma) = O(\sqrt{r n})$.

The constant can be calculated by integrating the tails, see for example 
https://www.hse.ru/data/2016/11/24/1113029206/Concentration%20inequalities.pdf